# How to find Max from Avg in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select
    max(total_price_new) 
from
    (select
         avg(Total_Price) as total_price_new, 
         Document_Ref  
     from
         TBL_Sales
     group by
         Document_Ref)
```

This works in SQLite but doesn't work in SQL Server 2008.

I get this error:

[image]

Can anyone know the alternate solution for this?

Comment: Do you get an error in SQL Server? If so - please **post the error** here since we can neither read your screen, nor your mind ....

Comment: I've added the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need  table name alias   eg Tname

```
select max(total_price_new) 
from  ( 
  select avg(Total_Price) as total_price_new, Document_Ref 
  from  TBL_Sales
group by Document_Ref
)  Tname
```

Answer (score 3):

You need an ***alias***(`q`) for your inner query :

```
select max(q.total_price_new) 
  from  ( select avg(Total_Price) as total_price_new, Document_Ref 
            from TBL_Sales
           group by Document_Ref) as q;
```

[*This*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017) reference may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When you  write any  inner sub-query then you have to put that sub-query name for selecting data into outer query  from that sub-query result, so you just need a alias of your sub-query

```
select
    max(total_price_new) 
from
    (select
         avg(Total_Price) as total_price_new, 
         Document_Ref  
     from
         TBL_Sales
     group by
         Document_Ref) as T
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery for this:

```
select top (1) avg(Total_Price) as total_price_new
from TBL_Sales
group by Document_Ref
order by total_price_new desc;
```

A nice advantage of this approach is that you can also pull back a `Document_Ref` with the highest average.